# How to display permissions again if user selects "Deny & dont ask again" without reinstalling the app?

Tags: android, android-permissions

On Android 6.0 and above it requires devs to manually display the check permissions screen for the user to select or deny. However after 1 deny, it then gives the option to `"Deny & don't ask again"`.

[image]

If the user accidently clicks the 3rd option, is it possible to display the permissions programmatically, without reinstalling the app?

Comment: nope . You can send user to setting with an Alert message just how every other app does .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are something that you need to check before every time you want to access the device's components like camera/storage. In case the user clicks on the option "**Deny and Don't ask again**" making them reinstall the app does not make any sense and is a very bad practice.

Instead, you need to show them an alert dialogue that consists of instructions about how they can enable the permission they need to by navigating to setting -> app setting -> app name -> permission and allow the permission. Since they can always change the permission setting from the user's phone setting app.